# CSS - Hover One Element, Change Visibility on Another

Tags: css

HTML is as Follows

```
<ul id="master">
 <li class="has-sub">Item</li>
   <ul class="sub">
    <li>Sub One</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS is

```
.sub { visibility: hidden; }
#master .has-sub:hover > .sub { visibility: visible;}
```

I pretty much took the approach from a site where this works, but on my adventure the hero fails. Badly.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the website where they this working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid...you have closed `<li class="has-sub">Item</li`> too soon.

```css
.sub {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#master .has-sub:hover > .sub {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul id="master">
    <li class="has-sub">Item
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>Sub One</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First your html is invalid please fix that
And Try this
Change your html to

```
  <ul id="master">
    <li class="has-sub">Item
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>Sub One</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

  .sub {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#master .has-sub:hover > .sub {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8swmj5o/)